# why the template not load having no error in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

i am trying load template  having no error in backbone.js but it is not display the text could you please tell where I am doing wrong ?
here is my code
http://goo.gl/OrGjRZ

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();
        ContactManager.addRegions({
            mainRegion:"#contend"
        })

        ContactManager.on("start", function(){
            console.log("ContactManager has started!");
            var routers = new R({app: ContactManager})

        });

        ContactManager.start();


    })

function render(tmpl_name, tmpl_data) {
    if ( !render.tmpl_cache ) {
        render.tmpl_cache = {};
    }

    if ( ! render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] ) {
        var tmpl_dir = '/root/template';
        var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + tmpl_name + '.html';

        var tmpl_string;
        $.ajax({
            url: tmpl_url,
            method: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                tmpl_string = data;
            }
        });

        render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string);
    }

    return render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data);
}
```

**Getting error:Uncaught ReferenceError: render is not defined**
I already defined the function in my code I don't know why I am getting this error?

Comment: please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: try to move render function in top of  your first.js file

Comment: or load first.js after render function in .html page

Comment: In render function you are using render object. Where is the definition of it?

Comment: I got it but how I fill show my view which is insude the template

Comment: @VahanVardanyan I'm pretty sure they're using a property of the `render` *function* for caching the templates. There's nothing wrong with that, functions can have properties like anything else.

Comment: @muistooshort you are right. They're trying to cache the templates for later use and it's not the best way of doing that. Almost the same behavior of the render function should be written in `Marionette.TemplateCache`'s `loadTemplate` function. And yes, there is nothing wrong with the `render` property.